# Problems with bootstrap form and POST Method

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap

i was making a simple page with a formulary using bootstrap and Eclipse (With JBoss).

Html code(Just < body > part):

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="validarIngresoAdmin.htm">
            <h4>Ingrese sus datos:</h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email" name="txtEmail">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password" name="txtPsw">     
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Iniciar sesi&#243n</button>    
        </form>
  </div>
```

but when i try to get the attributes txtEmail and txtPsw they return null.

Eclipse code:

```
private void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        String email = (String)request.getAttribute("txtEmail");
        String pass = (String)request.getAttribute("txtPsw");
    }
```

¿Why 'email' and 'pass' attributes return null?

P.S: Sorry about my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve http variables, you should be using `getParameter` rather than `getAttribute`.